# Module Circular Dependency with Function Pointer in C project

Tags: c, function-pointers, circular-dependency

I have a dilemma if function pointer should be used in the project:
I have a common module "master" which based on project setting can talk to one or more modules such as "slave1", "slave2", "slave3"...all of the slaves provide func such as

```
slave_x_init();
slave_x_send();
slave_x_receive();
(where x = 1, 2, 3...)
```

Right now I have project specific files which calls these functions accordingly, and it works well. But seems like using function pointer table would be helpful to unify the interface design for any new slaves.

```
typedef struct {
    init_t init_func;
    send_t send_func;
    receive_t receive_func;
} master_interface_t;
(xxx_t is the function pointer)
```

My only problem with this approach is I have to include a header file from "master" now which has the struct definition, and this seems to cause a circular dependency between master and slave module. Is there a way to solve this, or even is this a good approach for the interface design?

### Update:

Folks have suggested to have a different header file such as "master-intf.h" to separate the interface struct from the main APIs in master module. I am still curious if we ever need a new master, say master_v2 for future projects (master and master_v2 are gonna be mutually exclusive, meaning only one of them is gonna be compiled in one project) , then the slave will have to be modified to include the same header from master_v2, seems not ideal to me?

Here is an example of the modules...

```
|
|- master
|---- master.c
|---- master.h
|---- master_interface.h
|- master_v2
|---- master_v2.c
|---- master_v2.h
|---- master_v2_interface.h
|- slave1
|---- slave1.c
|- slave2
|---- slave2.c
```

Based on project either master or master_v2 would be compiled, this would cause in slaveX.c to have the below #ifdef usage would seems difficult to manage over time.

```
#ifdef PROJECT1
#include "master/master_interface.h"
#elif PROJECT2
#include "master_v2/master_v2_interface.h"
#endif
```

.

Comment: The master interface doesn't have to be in the same header where most of the masters functionality is included. It can and probably should be in its own small header that both master and slaves include.

Comment: The 'master-slave' common interface information should be in a separate header (call it `master-slave.h`) which can be included by `master.h` and by each of the `slave.h` files.  That should break any cyclic dependencies.  Properly designed, there shouldn't be a problem.  To be able to help you with more than such general statements, we'd need to see an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Without the MCVE, we're unlikely to be able to help much more.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's true. I do have a separate header file in master, e.g. master_interface.h. But I still see the problem if I need to come up with a "master2" later, now slave needs to include the header from a different module, which doesn't seem ideal to me

Comment: If a slave has two masters, you have bigger problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Thanks for the advice. But I still have the concern as commented above.

Comment: Yup, but if the master and the slave(s) have to share some common definitions (seems plausible), then regarding the common material as belonging to either 'the master' or 'the slave(s)' is misguided; it belongs to both, or neither.  So, the common information isn't "from a different module"; it is shared between the different modules.  The multi-master scenario isn't clear to me yet, either.

Comment: @StoryTeller the two masters would be mutual-exclusive in the project. I think that would be common?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure. I've made the edit which has a basic example. Hopefully this would be more clear to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Here's your problem. If the interface for master_v2 is so different that each slave needs to have conditional compilation applied, your projects aren't modular enough, and master_v2 should have different slaves. And if the interface isn't different at all, then there shouldn't be a different header for each master. It doesn't belong to any individual master.

Comment: If the Master V2 maintains the same interface as the original (V1?) Master, then there's no need to modify the slaves as they use the same structures as before. If Master V2 is different, then the slaves have to be recompiled using the V2 definitions. You can choose either — it is up to you to decide what is constant. For simplicity, you should aim to keep the interface unchanged. You do that by 'fossilizing' the interface specification. Programmers are not allowed to change the interface — only the implementations of the interface. If the interface evolves, the slaves have to evolve too.

Comment: I see. Thanks both for the advice. Completely agree that the interface header file for both v1 and v2 should be maintained as the same unless it really needs to evolve. Probably the master_interface.h should be moved to the top level instead of inside any of the master module for better clarity.